# How to use redux in a vanilla js class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, redux

I have a javascript class - not a React component - that acts as a service to handle logic tier (api call, etc.) in a React application. Its methods all use redux (useSelector or useDispatch), and everything works fine.

However, the linter goes mad:

> React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called in a class component.

The class looks like this:

```js
export class UserService implements ProjectService {
  private userService: UserService;
  constructor(dependencies: Dependencies) {
    this.userService = dependencies.userService;
  }
  public updateUserProfile(id: string) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (user: User) => {
      return dispatch(Event.userManager(user));
    };
  }
}
```

How to refactor this?

Comment: You can use [react-redux connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), not sure why you need a class, just put userService in a useRef.

Comment: How would you wrap this service in a ref?

Comment: `const service = useRef(); useEffect(()=>{service.current = new userService();},[]);` If you need userService instance on first render then don't render first time: `return service.current ? null : <jsx content`

Answer (score 0):

To access redux, it depends on your context:

- in React function component: use react-redux hooks or connect
- in React class component: use react-redux connect
- outside a React class: use [redux Store API](https://redux.js.org/api/store) :

```
import { store } from "where you create and export your store";
store.dispatch({type: ... });
const events = store.getState().events;
store.subscribe(() => console.log("The store has been modified"));
```

Comment: This solution looks promising, but I have the following error: "Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type '(reducers?: ReducersMapObject<any, Action<any>>, extendedRootSaga?: Saga<any[]>) => Store<CombinedState<{ router: RouterState<{}>; user: Partial<User>; ... 4 more ...;" .

Comment: The error message suggests that you are calling dispatch on a *reducer*. You should instead call dispatch on your *store instance*. Your store instance is the object returned by createStore.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import store and use `getState()` to get data example below

```
import { store } from "../../../redux/store";
// getting state data from redux
const state = store.getState();
//fecth the data from initial state where you have stored
const data = state.rootReducerName.initialStateObjectName;
```

For example below redux image and code

[image]

```
state = store.getState();
const data = state.valuemodel.estimatorData;
```